# home directory is unpreferable location in msys2 shell in integrated teriminal of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

I want to use msys2 as a integrated terminal in vscode, so I added this configulation to my user setting.json in vscode.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "MSYS2 UCRT64": {
        "path": [
            "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
        ],
        "args": [
            "--login",
            "-i"
        ],
        "env": {
            "MSYSTEM": "UCRT64",
            "CHERE_INVOKING": "1",
            "MSYS2_PATH_TYPE": "inherit"
        }
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "MSYS2 UCRT64",
```

And  when I open the vscode and toggle terminal window, the msys2 launch, but its start folder is not the same with the one when I launch it from installed location(c/msys64/ucrt64.exe).

```
shumbow@DESKTOP-STEUAV4 UCRT64 /c/Users/shumbow
$ pwd
/c/Users/shumbow
```

This is when I launch it from install location.

```
shumbow@DESKTOP-STEUAV4 UCRT64 ~
$ pwd
/home/shumbow
```

Could anyone teach me the way I can make these two same?

Comment: Isn't this the effect of `CHERE_INVOKING`? Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

@HolyBlackCat Removing the CHERE_INVOKING env variable did the trick!(answer by HolyBlackCat). Thanks.